# RxJs: How to "listen" to change on a subscription when it receives a stream?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I'm new with Angular 2 and Observables, but I haven't found a way to "listen" to change on a subscription when it receives a stream, I don't even know if this is possible or if it's the right way.

This is what I used to do with promises:

```
// Constructor and more code
// ...

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading.present();

  this.getItems()
      .then(() => this.loading.dismiss());
}

getItems(): Promise {
  return this.itemService
    .getItems()
    .then(items => this.items = items);
}

refresh(refresher): void {
  this.getItems()
      .then(() => refresher.complete());
}
```

I've tried it with subscription/observables but I just don't know how:

```
// Constructor and more code
// ...

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading.present();

  this.getItems()
      .subscribe(() => this.loading.dismiss());
}

getItems(): Subscription {
  return this.itemService
    .getItems()
    .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
}

refresh(refresher): void {
  this.getItems()
      .subscribe(() => refresher.complete());
}
```

And of course, I get a compilation error: `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'`, any help on how to achieve this with Observables (RxJS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Subscription` is a listener, you can't listen to a listener, can you?

Instead, you need to return an `Observable` to be able to subscribe to. Change your function to be as follow (not tested):

```
getItems(): Observable<any> {
  let obs = this.itemService.getItems().share();
  obs.subscribe(items => this.items = items);
  return obs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was doing it wrong, I just didn't know how to do it right